# How to capitalize every word including in the beginning of a quote?

Tags: python

For example, this sentence:

```
say "mosquito!"
```

I try to capitalize with the following code:

```
'say "mosquito!"'.capitalize()
```

Which returns this:

```
'Say "mosquito!"’
```

However, the desired result is:

```
'Say "Mosquito!"’
```

Comment: `title()` function `a = 'say "mosquito!"'` and then `result = a.title()` result returns `Say "Mosquito!"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite tricky. I will look for the first letter (alphabet) of a word.  Split the string into words and join them again after converting the first letter of each word in upper case.

```
def start(word):
    for n in range(len(word)):
        if word[n].isalpha():
            return n
    return 0

strng = 'say mosquito\'s house'
print( ' '.join(word[:start(word)] + word[start(word)].upper() + word[start(word)+1:] for word in strng.split()))
```

Result:

```
Say "Mosquito's House"
```

Comment: Is there any way to not make this code get rid of newlines? Because it simply deletes newlines.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `str.title`:

```
print('say "mosquito!"'.title())

# Output: Say "Mosquito!"
```

Looks like Python has a built-in method for this!

Comment: How can I prevent it capitalizing after a single quote. For example this will capitalize the s after the single quote:

print('say "mosquito\'s house"'.title())

Comment: `from string import capwords` then `capwords("mosquito\'s house")`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a lambda in regular expression substitution:

```
string = 'say "mosquito\'s house" '  

import re
caps   = re.sub("((^| |\")[a-z])",lambda m:m.group(1).upper(),string)

# 'Say "Mosquito\'s House" '
```